# Can I make a helix with 4 strands?

Tags: modifiers

Ok... I've been tinkering with Blender for years but the interface always turned me off.  Recently I have decided to make a go of actually learning to use Blender.  I have 2.93 and recently I have started trying 3.0.  I can do some basic modeling stuff but some things just don't work the way I seem to "think" that they're supposed to.  Simple deform is one of them.

I want to make a helix out of 4 symmetrical strands.  I have successfully done so with 2 strands ( essentially cylinders subdivided really small).  But when I create a mirror of that same strand so that there are 4 strands... the simple deform goes all wonky.  It creates a simple spiral and nothing I do makes it even close to a helix shape.  I have looked for videos and all the videos are different versions and some of the options are completely different.

Can it be done?  I know there is an addon but I am flat broke right now.  The 4 strands should twist around the axis just like the 2 strand helix does.  But nothing I do gets anywhere near what I am looking for.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a little 'Rope' GN node group to make a multi-strand helix from any curve you set it to modify:

[image]

..With this sort of result:

[image]

[image]

(Blender 3.0b)

Comment: That's a really nice solution with Geometry Nodes.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann maybe not strictly an answer to the OP, but just hoping to improve Cloudrunner's UX :)

Comment: Definitely yes, and I like it because I'm at the very beginning of using GN.

Answer (score 9):

You can create a single object that is four circles of vertices placed where you want them.  The origin of the object will be the center of rotation.

[image]

Use the *Screw Modifier* to extrude a shape up along the Z axis by entering some distance into the *Screw* field.  Mind the *Steps* values to smooth out the shape.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try that for sure

Comment: Bummer... I followed your instrcutions to the letter and somehow is is making a spiral with 3 of the circles and the 4th is centered on the origin.  It makes no sense.  Any suggestions?

Comment: +1... maybe you could mention the option of  tilting the profile-circles, so they are orthogonal to the sweep direction?

Comment: OK... I had to add an empty object at the origin to set as the axis object.  Now we're rockin.  Thanx.

Comment: last one looks like a cool circular staircase handrail

Answer (score 4):

Here's another possibility, as you said you've created it with a subdivided cylinder. Now if you have that single cylinder you can create multiple strand helices by doing the following (but note that this also works with Allen's answer, if you created a single helix with the *Screw Modifier* you can jump to point 3):

1. Put a *SimpleDeform* modifier on it, use the *Twist* option, *Angle* whatever you like (720° in my example) and the *Axis* to *Z* for a vertical helix.

[image: simpledeform]

2. Now in *Edit Mode* move the cylinder out of the center until it creates a single helix you like, to directly view the result while you're editing make sure *Display modifier in Edit mode* is enabled.

[image: move mesh]

3. Back in *Object Mode* add an *Empty* at the origin of the helix.

[image: add empty]

4. Select the helix and add an *Array Modifier*. For the offset, disable the default *Relative Offset* and enable *Object Offset*. Choose the *Empty* as object. For a start, leave the *Count* at the default value 2.

[image: array modifier]

5. If you now start rotating the *Empty* on the Z axis, the second helix duplicate gets rotated around the center. You can of course any angle you like, for regular even distances you should use 360° divided the *Count* of the *Array Modifier*, e.g. 180° for a double helix, 120° for a triple helix and 90° for a quadruple helix.

[image: rotate empty]

Here are different examples, of course you don't have to use a regular even distance if you want the helices closer together:

[image: examples]

Answer (score 4):

Here the classic way - i cannot believe I am providing the classic solution ‍♀️ - but i think mooonboots will appreciate it :)

1. Add Helix

> Note: you need this add-on (built-in):

[image]

[image]

2. adjust the values to your needs

[image]

3. add empty
4. add array modifier to your curve, count 4, object offset: empty

[image]

5. rotate your empty by 90 degrees

[image]

6. give your curve some bevel depth value

[image]

result:

[image]

> Note: this is all non-destructive and you can still change anything as
> you like, or add some more modifier, to get something interesting like
> the simple deform modifier...

[image]

Comment: Nice one Chris!

Comment: Thank you‼️‼️‼️‼️