# How can I apply a screwed object to a curve/path?

Tags: screw-modifier, curve-modifier

So I am watching a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ebx2qbBlvh0 13.57 min) when a screwed object comes into play. Can someone explain to me what´s happening? I tried using the pipette in combination with the objects, but it didn´t work. So how can you apply a screwed objct to a path, to give my teddy a mouth?
[image: teddys smile]

here´s my file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ic3h3vkoz0dp0m5/teddy_low.blend?dl=0

Comment: Not strictly an answer.. but Geometry Nodes has [made this a lot easier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/243995/35559)

Comment: I find this to be the easier way to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Apply the rotation of your curve
- Put the screw object at the same position as the curve with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected* then *Selection to Cursor*
- Choose *Deform Axis > Z* in the *Curve* modifier.
- adapt the iterations in the screw modifier so that it fits

Comment: …but this does not perfectly cover the mouth…

Comment: mmh yes it does, what do you mean? You can reduce the iterations in the Screw modifier if you want to make it shorter

Comment: result, if i made it....is this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyihl.png

Comment: i updated your answer so that i could upvote your answer ;)

Comment: I don´t understand how using "Cursor to Selected" and "Selection to Cursor" is supposed to help. I put screw and curve (BezierCurve) with alt + G at the same position. How is it possible to make both objects affect one another? That´s what I am missing here... Ah nevermind, it did somehow work out.

Comment: it is supposed to put the screw object at the same location as the curve, otherwise it won't stick to it

Comment: You did forget to mention to chose Curve Object on the Curve Modifier...

Comment: mmh it is already selected from what I see...

Comment: It is, but that little monitor icon was deselected.