# How can I animate a rope falling into a coil

Tags: animation

I need to have a rope being slowly let down from a constant point forming a spiral or coil shape

Comment: You might be able to adapt the mechanism from [this youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/lw0UcHhcAk4). If you wind the rope around something that's not visible in the render and don't anchor the other end, it might give you what you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Winding around the outside of a coil or spiral while keeping the inside static is an old rigging bugbear .. (rolling carpets, scrolls, etc) Most tutorials cheat.. the item slides along a spiral towards the middle, and the inside of the coil is made progressively tighter.

Geometry Nodes come to the rescue.. they give you great control over curves. A curve can be trimmed from either end, it can be resampled at any stage, and its endpoints can be located after trimming.

[image]

Here:

- A smooth Bezier spiral is created
- It's progressively (un)trimmed on the loose (outside) end
- The outside pair of control points are raised a little
- The outermost point is raised a lot (more than the total rope-length), and drawn towards the center in XY
- The whole curve is trimmed from the raised end to a constant rope-length

[image]

Finally the curve is converted to a rope, using the GN group from [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/243995/35559)

You could get a lot more sophisticated about centering the loose end, etc., if you wanted to, with more nodes.. GN lets you in at any stage, to move end-points, trim to length.. almost whatever you like.

[image]

Comment: Very nice, simple and clear! +1

Comment: @quellenform Thank you! I've been enjoying your GN solutions. There are a couple of places I've been tempted to play 'Node Golf' with you, pulling some GN tricks to save nodes: (eg the bisector of 2 curve edges is the X direction of the curve normal at that point.. using extrusion and _Edge Angle_ to find the angle between 2 edges..). But while the tricks might save nodes, they are often actually more expensive, so I wind up preferring your way.. doing the hard maths :D.

Comment: Thank you so much for this feedback! I learn a lot from you! In fact, my solutions are mostly based on trial and error, and there are definitely people with more mathematical knowledge. However, I often like to think outside the box and use unconventional approaches. As a result, I sometimes come up with ideas that others like to keep hidden, and solutions that you wouldn't even think of as such at first ;-)