# How do I do animate hair strand in blender?

Tags: animation, hair

I want to animate Hair in such a way that it wraps around naturally around an object. How can I achieve it in blender ?

[image: example image 1]

[image: example image 2]

Comment: You could rig to an armature?

Comment: I tried That, The hair strand needs to be wrap around the cylinder and should look natural
I have tired using force fields , It gives me half of the desired animation

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76756/animate-winding-a-ribbon-rope-cable-around-a-cylinder https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260335/how-can-i-animate-a-rope-falling-into-a-coil/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183182/animating-wire-cable-rope-wrapping-around-a-cylinder https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121357/how-to-create-a-cable-wire-for-animation/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/how-to-get-the-physics-engine-to-wraps-a-string-around-the-moving-part-of-a-moto

Comment: Thank you for the input, 
This Link solves 90% of my problem : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/how-to-get-the-physics-engine-to-wraps-a-string-around-the-moving-part-of-a-moto